# Why do I have 2 SSH services?

Tags: services

The command: `sudo netstat -ntulp` gives me:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1263/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1357/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1857/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1357/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1857/apache2
```

Why is sshd listed twice? And what's the difference between 0.0.0.0:22 and :::22?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal, `0.0.0.0:22` is IPv4, `:::22` is IPv6.

The fact that both lines are related to the same PID shows that you have only one SSH Daemon.

Comment: Oh, you're obviously right! I missed the tcp6.
So this wouldn't be the message I'm getting from a PCI scan: "unknown service found on tcp port: 22"?

Comment: What do you mean by "PCI scan"?

Comment: A scan for PCI compliance. Also known as PCI-DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard)

Comment: As I said, it's normal when you run `sshd` on both IPv4 and IPv6.  Do check with the rule book though whether you're allowed to run `sshd` in the first place.